# Числа между двумя датами

Tags: php, дата

Доброе время суток, пытаюсь вывести числа месяца начиная от понедельника текущей недели заканчивая определенной датой. И тут ступор, написал функцию которая генерирует дни недели от текущего понедельника, но она прибавляет 14 дней, а нужно именно до определенной даты

```
$date_start = strtotime('last Monday');
            
for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', $date_start + ($i * 86400));
}
```

Comment: ну так у вас в цикле написано 14 дней. Поменяйте цикл на `while (условие)`

Comment: $date = '2021-10-25';
 $end_date = '2021-11-7';

 while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
     
     $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
 
     
  
 }        при таком способе работает, но выводит даты с 26 по 8, а мне нужно с 25 по 7 мое

Comment: ну так сначала выводите, а потом делайте `+1 day`. И я бы предложил вам всё же перейти на `date_create` или `date_create_immutable`, чем каждый раз вызывать `strtotime`